# How do you append data to array struct with * pointer

Tags: go, pointers, struct, slice

i'm learning the basics of golang, and i stumbled upon something that i may lack understanding about it, this code works fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Category struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}

type Book struct {
    Id         int
    Name       string
    Categories []Category
}

func main() {

    var book Book

    book.Id = 1
    book.Name = "Vanaraj"

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        book.Categories = append(book.Categories, Category{
            Id:   10,
            Name: "Vanaraj",
        })
    }

    fmt.Println(book)

}

Output:
{1 Vanaraj [{10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj}]}
```

But adding * pointer on []Category break the program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Category struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}

type Book struct {
    Id         int
    Name       string
    Categories *[]Category
}

func main() {

    var book Book

    book.Id = 1
    book.Name = "Vanaraj"

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        book.Categories = append(book.Categories, Category{
            Id:   10,
            Name: "Vanaraj",
        })
    }

    fmt.Println(book)

}

Output:
./prog.go:26:27: first argument to append must be slice; have *[]Category
```

Now let's say i can't remove the * from []Category on the second block of code (Case example is importing a package), how can i still append data like the first block of the code with only adding codes to my main() function? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as using an `int` value or an `*int` pointer.

```
var p *int
```

You have to initialize it first, e.g. with using the builtin `new()`:

```
p = new(int)
```

You assign to the pointed value:

```
*p = 3
fmt.Println(*p)
```

The same goes with pointer slices: you first have to initialize it, e.g. with using the builtin `new()`:

```
book.Categories = new([]Category)
```

And you dereference the pointer using `*`:

```
*book.Categories = append(*book.Categories, Category{
    Id:   10,
    Name: "Vanaraj",
})
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-rqB9Lbw5d1).

Please note that slices are slice headers which already contain a pointer to a backing array. So using pointers to slices is very rare, usually unneeded and just complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

```
func main() {

var book Book

book.Id = 1
book.Name = "Vanaraj"
book.Categories = new([]Category)

for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    *book.Categories = append(*book.Categories, Category{
        Id:   10,
        Name: "Vanaraj",
    })
}

fmt.Println(book)}
```

Ouput : `{1 Vanaraj 0xc00000c030}`

And to print categories you can use `fmt.Println(book.Categories)`